# Can't install gems with rvm as non-root user

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm

```
$ gem install sinatra
Fetching: rack-1.5.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 directory.
```

On my `/etc/profile` I already inserted:

```
source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Note: I'm using vagrant, and the group:user is `admin:vagrant`. Also, if this is relevant:

```
$ echo $GEM_HOME
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

Answer (score 2):

try add this line: `gem: --user-install` in `$HOME/.gemrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

use `rvm gem install sinatra`. Don't use `sudo` it can cause problems.

Comment: This is displaying a warning telling me to go use `gem install sinatra` instead.

Comment: Also, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853489/installing-gems-using-rvm?rq=1